# why do i need call props twice to get the Array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im studing React and my component (MyPost.jsx) need array trough props from index.js and it goes trough all components index.js -> App.js-->Profile.jsx--> MyPost.jsx.

So props are  =>  => let post = Post_postsData.Post_postsData.Profile_postsData.App_postsData

Why do i need to double call Post_postData to get the Array of objects?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe it's because when defining the parameters in the App function definition you take all the props and take it as App_postData instead of passing to Profile_postData something like: `App_postData.App_postData`.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer, if it's incomplete or unsatisfactory, please comment so I can edit it :)

Comment: The smarter thing would be to call the parameter received in App something like "props" and then you know that App_postData is inside of that.

Comment: quick fix is to destructure props to get the desired property: `function App(App_postsData)` => `function App({App_postsData})`

Comment: @Maksymsly Any questions, please comment so I can edit my answer, I wish you success on your journey :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Example Code:

---

Please see this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-framework-fqxqin?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

function Example(props) {
  return <h2>{props.abc}</h2>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Example abc={123} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Each attribute passed to the react component is passed as a property in the function.

Ie: Example is an React component, , i`m passing the abc attribute that will be accesible in (props)

### Explanation:

---

##### Function and Class Components

The simplest way to define a component is to write a JavaScript function:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element. We call such components “function components” because they are literally JavaScript functions.

##### Rendering a Component

```
const element = <Example abc="Any value" />;
```

When React sees an element representing a user-defined component, it passes `JSX attributes` and children to this component as a single object. We call this object “props”.

**JSX attributes:** 
These are attributes equivalent to the same attributes of an HTML element, such as style, id, class and other user-defined attributes such as data- etc, example:  (The `div` element has two attributes, namely, `id` and `example`, their values being respectively **123** and **abc**)

##### How React works:

It will take each JSX attribute, and pass it in JSON format to your function, so:

`<Example App_postsData="abc"/>`, inside the example function will be accessible via props.App_postsData:

```
function Example(props){
    const value = props.App_postsData;
}
```

Or simply:

```
function Example({App_postsData}){}
```

---

Why does the example given by @kengru work?

> `function Example({App_postsData}){}`

In javascript we can access data from a JSON in two ways:

**1:**

```
const JSON = { example: 123 } 
const example = JSON.example;
```

//The variable `const example` have the value 123

**2:**

```
const JSON = { example: 123 }
const { example } = JSON;
```

//The variable `const example` have the value 123

Answer (score 0):

It's very obvious, you're not destrcuturing an passing down the posts array, but using the props directly.

It should be:

App.jsx

```
function App({App_postsData}) {/*...*/}
```

Profile.jsx

```
function Profile ({Profile_postsData}) {/*...*/}
```

MyPosts.jsx

```
function Post ({Post_postsData}) {/*...*/}
```